# SQL Query for below scenario for multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need response as per expected result column in attached image.
The row filtration is required in multiple rows

[image]

The rule is (x.attr2 = '1' AND x.attr3 = '1') AND (x.attr2='' AND x.attr3='2') then its expected column value is  true but all other conditions its false

Its MS SQL

```
Key Atr2    Atr3    expected result
111  1       1      TRUE
111  2       2  
112  1       4      FALSE
113  1       4      FALSE
113  2       2  
114  1       1      FALSE
```

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: What's the rule to compute the expected result?

Comment: No clue what youre asking for.

Comment: Why does the `Key` column allow duplicates?

Comment: MS SQL DB , Key column doesn't meant primary key its just main key to join in

Comment: please edit your question rather than commenting, moreover share you data as text rather than image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the below script-

```
IF OBJECT_ID('[Sample]') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE [Sample]

CREATE TABLE [Sample]
(
[Key] INT NOT NULL,
Attr1 INT NOT NULL,
Attr2 INT NOT NULL,
Attr3 INT NOT NULL
)
GO

INSERT INTO [Sample] ([Key],Attr1,Attr2,Attr3)
VALUES (111,62,1,1),
(111,62,2,2),
(112,62,1,4),
(113,62,1,4),
(113,62,2,2),
(114,62,1,1)

--EXPECTED_RESULT:
SELECT S.*,CASE WHEN T.[KEY] IS NOT NULL THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS Expected_Result 
FROM [Sample] S LEFT JOIN
( 
SELECT T.[KEY] FROM
(
SELECT x.*,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY x.[KEY],x.attr1 ORDER BY x.attr2,x.attr3) AS r_no
--,CASE WHEN (x.attr2 = 1 AND x.attr3 = 1) OR (x.attr2 = 2 AND x.attr3 = 2) 
--then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end as expected_result
FROM [Sample] x WHERE x.attr2=x.attr3
) T WHERE T.r_no>1
) T ON S.[KEY]=T.[KEY]
```

Answer (score 0):

This query:

```
select key from tablename
group by key
having sum(case when atr2 = '1' and atr3 = '1' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
   and sum(case when atr2 = '2' and atr3 = '2' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
   and count(*) = 2
```

uses conditional aggregation to find the keys for which the result should be `true`.
So join it to the table like this:

```
select t.*, 
  case when g.[key] is null then 'FALSE' else 'TRUE' end result
from tablename t left join (
  select [key] from tablename
  group by [key]
  having sum(case when atr2 = '1' and atr3 = '1' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
     and sum(case when atr2 = '2' and atr3 = '2' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
     and count(*) = 2
) g on g.[key] = t.[key]
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bddf0a9b265a455cbe88c3c07f643af5).
Results:

```
> Key | Atr2 | Atr3 | result
> --: | ---: | ---: | :-----
> 111 |    1 |    1 | TRUE  
> 111 |    2 |    2 | TRUE  
> 112 |    1 |    4 | FALSE 
> 113 |    1 |    4 | FALSE 
> 113 |    2 |    2 | FALSE 
> 114 |    1 |    1 | FALSE
```

Comment: Attribute is varchar value & other rows can have different values not just INT values

Comment: Thank you so much @forpas  both solution working , thanks for input

Comment: Hey @forpas, yes your answer is also correct & works for me but it seems I can choose only 1 .Sorry for that but really appreciate your help.